# Implement OpenIdDict auth backend(Asp.Net core) to be able to auth with model entity and LinkedIn authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, linkedin-api, openiddict

The goal is to be able to login in mobile app(react native) with:

- in app `username and password`
- `"Login with LinkedId"` feature.

I've researched a lot on this topic, and read the Kévin Chalet's(@Pinpoint) blog series and also cloned the sampels from: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples

I've created test server app:https://github.com/Jamaxack/OpenIdConnectAuthLinkedIn

I'm able to test the authorization to LinkedIn with https://oidcdebugger.com but now, I'm confused. Without https://oidcdebugger.com how can I test the LinkedIn authorization? for example with Postman? For my case what Auth flow should I use?

```
 options.AllowImplicitFlow()
        .AllowPasswordFlow()
        .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
        .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Authorization Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context) to login using Linkedin and request permission from the member .

If using Postman , you can try below steps :

1. Add a new request , click the `Authorization` , choose `OAuth 2.0` as `TYPE` , and set `Add authorization data to` to `Request Headers` . If you want to inspect the authorization headers and parameters that Postman generates, click the Preview Request button.
2. Click the `Get New Access Token` button . Input the correct callback url, auth url, token url , client id, client secret and scopes , callback url should match the one register in linkedin application portal .

   [image]
3. Now you should now see a screen prompting you to login to your LinkedIn account. After click `Allow` in Application Authorization Confirmation page , you will get token in Postman .
4. Making a `Get` request to api `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` with token as authorization bearer token header , and you will get the correct response from linkedin API endpoint .

Comment: Appreciate your answer. It makes sense to me now to use AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow() to be able to authorize with LinkedIn, but what about authentication with local username and password(user data is stored in app database) should I enable also in settings AllowPasswordFlow() and AllowImplicitFlow()?

Comment: That is different , you can use linkedin as external identity provider , the process is when  your native application need login , it will redirect to OpenID auth server , user could choose use social login with asp.net identity or choose use linkedin login , after linkedin login ,  OpenIdDict auth server will get the claims and create it's own token and back to your native application , your native application will decode token and get the user claims.

Comment: Another process is your native application directly pass username/password to your  OpenID auth server , if credential is correct , it directly return token to your native application , that is resource owner flow , this flow doesn't use linkedin auth .

Comment: So that your OpenID auth server should both enable code flow( .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()) and also resource owner flow(.AllowPasswordFlow()) .  They are different authentication process